# Finding lowest score in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am using the below javascript program that should fing the lowest score and remove it from the collection

```
var types=['exam','homework','quiz']
for (student_id = 0; student_id < 800; student_id++){
    for(type = 0; type < 3; type++){
        var r = {'student_id':student_id, 'type':types[type], 'minscore':{'$min':'$scores'}};
        db.scores.remove(r);
    }
}
```

i am getting the error:

```
WriteResult({
        "nRemoved" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 2,
                "errmsg" : "unknown operator: $min"
        }
```

Comment: Why not a `sort()` and a `limit()`. `db.getCollection('students').find({}).sort({scores:1}).limit(1)`?

Comment: if you want the smallest value of a field across documents then you need to aggregate and use $min operator in $group stage or the $project stage (if your mongo version has the $project stage).

Answer (score 3):

This is the raw mongo query that will get you what you want.  One line.

`db.scores.find({'student_id':student_id, 'type':types[type]}).sort({scores: 1}).limit(1);`

Remember to make sure there is an index with all queried fields so you get the best possible speed.

Comment: so i do away with the iteration

Comment: Yes, no reason to do it and it's more than likely a lot slower.  (Also please flag the answer as the correct one if it helped!  :)  )